# Neo4j versioning graph/nodes/relationships, checkpointing

Tags: neo4j, cypher, versioning, checkpoint

We would like to keep snapshots/versions of the graph(or just versions of a specific node). We would want to switch to any version (like in a git repo).

We tried using GraphAware's ChangeFeed but that doesn't solve our purpose.

We have also found this github project: https://github.com/dmontag/neo4j-versioning. But it is too outdated.

Are there any plugins which can help us in achieving this?

Comment: GraphAware's ChangeFeed module has a complete different purpose. There are currently no modules/extensions out of the box, but you might want to read / watch these 2 resources : http://iansrobinson.com/2014/05/13/time-based-versioned-graphs/ --- http://jexp.github.io/graphgist/?40364ac2a52f57aa520a

Comment: I collected some different approaches here, preparing for a blog post: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14493611/versioning_neo4j.adoc perhaps you find something helpful in there?

Comment: Amazing collection of resources, thanks for sharing

Comment: Hi, thanks for the resources posted. After a lot of thought I decided to follow the model as in https://github.com/dmontag/neo4j-versioning, but then realized that reverting to a particular state is problematic. So, still stuck. 

Though on second thoughts I am starting to think that this combination might make my life easier in djnago-python: neo4jdjango and djnago-reversion

Comment: hi :-) did you had any luck with this issue , we struggling with the same problem - managing date based versioning of our data model . 10x

Comment: Sorry for a late comment. Unfortunately not a very good solution. But we specifically have every change logged in a mysql db. For every node if a label is changed, a property added, deleted - we logged this is a relational backed. Similarly for relations. This way we were able to account for every change - we were able to construct current graph.

But this solution has better logging/accountability advantages. Nothing more I believe. Let me know is this works or if you have a better solution.